# How to get active users count and active devices for a particular android app in google play console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

i want to find count of user for specific version of android application uploaded on beta in google play console.can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Go to the statistics page and change the `Select <...> to display` option to `App version`. Then pick the app version you're interested in.

Comment: got it ,thank you so much